# setting a selector in a destination view controller when preparing to segue

Tags: objective-c

i want to move from viewControllerA to viewControllerB and in my prepareForSegue assign the selector of a navigation item in viewControllerB.

in viewControllerA.m

```
prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    vcB = (viewControllerB *)segue.destinationViewController;
    vcB.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem.title = @"cancel";
    vcB.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem.selector(unwindWithCancel);
}
```

and still in viewControllerA.m

```
-(void)unwindWithCancel
{
    NSLog(@"unwindWithCancel");
}
```

the `navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem`'s title does change but the selector doesn't work. i know you can drag and drop the button on viewControllerB's "Exit" to trigger this selector but in future i want to change the selector depending on which sender in viewControllerA has triggered the segue.

any help is much appreciated.

thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you also need to set the target of the selector:

```
...
    vcB.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem.target = self
...
```